# Trendline in GraphView?

Tags: android, android-graphview

Is there a way in GraphView to graph and find the equation of a linear trendline that represents the data points on a line graph?

I'm looking at the documentation and although there's instructions about creating a line graph and making it look nice, I can't really find anything else. Should I just write my own function or is there an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no trendline in GraphView (at least from what I know of).